# Loss values significantly different when comparing Tensorflow 2.0.0 and 1.13.1 and using class_weight

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I'm fitting a multiclass - multilabel classification model on two machines: the first one is a Linux server running Tensorflow 1.13.1 and the second one is running Windows with Tensorflow 2.0.0.
The code and the data on both machines are exactly the same. In my final call to the `fit` function I'm using `class_weight` argument to address class inbalance issues:

```
model %>% compile(
  optimizer = "rmsprop",
  loss = "binary_crossentropy",
  metrics = c("accuracy") 
)

history <- model %>% fit(
  x_train, y_train,
  epochs = 30,
  batch_size = 256,
  validation_split = 0.1,
  callbacks = list(
    callback_early_stopping(patience = 5),
    callback_reduce_lr_on_plateau(factor = 0.1)
  ),
  class_weight = list("0" = 13.914, "1" = 4.974, "2" = 41.625, "3" = 111.706, "4" = 125.936, "5" = 1.119, 
         "6" = 23.179, "7" = 1, "8" = 2.805, "9" = 2.054, "10" = 4.665, "11" = 17.045, "12" = 1.156)
)
```

On the Linux machine, the best validation loss value that I get is 0.14 but on Windows it's 0.46. If I remove the `class_weight` argument, both machines return a similar value. (Training and validation data sizes are large enough so that the differences are not result of random fluctuations. Increasing the number of epochs won't help because best fit is reached before 30.)

Why is this happening? Is it possible that both models are approximately the same and that Tensorflow 2.0.0 only uses a different formula for computation of loss with class weigths?

**Edit:** I've plotted density plots showing model predictions (probabilities) vs. true values on test set and they look the same on both versions. I've also compared predicted values on a few cases and they too are alomost the same. So I guess this is not an issue I should worry about.

**Edit 2:**
After upgrading the Windows version to Tensorflow 2.7, the validation loss I get is 0.10. It has changed from significantly higher to significantly lower value. The model convergence graph that I get with `plot(history)` is much different now. It shows that the training loss is much higher than the validation loss. I suspect this happens because class_weights are not accounted for on validation data. Density plots on test data still look the same though. So I guess the lesson here is that all models perform about the same and that loss values are just not comparable across versions.

Comment: It's worth noting that both versions are quite old. You might try upgrading to 1.15.0, or 2.7, and seeing if you see similar issues.

Comment: Thanks. I've upgraded the Windows installation to 2.7 and now validation loss there is 0.10.